# How to fix fade hover background image after of background image changer button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, background, switch-statement

I was figuring it out how to fix, but i gave up...

There some 2 potential bugs are:

1# This is kind of advanced UI like videogame, this bar come with grayscale color, then mouse over at bar it changes grey to red and black in fade effect. Then you press a button to slide down this bar, the hover is disabled but there a problem that grey area is not out.

The image is a CSS sprite.

[image: CSS Sprite for this bar]

2# When you press some buttons below from bar, it changes textures on background with fade effect also it applies to hover background, but it definetly removes hover...

I really need a help, there my fiddle i hope you can understand this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JBFUT/7/

Biggest thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're supporting newer browsers, I would re-work this with rgba and CSS opacity on `:hover`

For older browsers you can use two images. One a grayscale version of what you have, and another a gradient transparent to red that you can place on top and on hover fadeOut.

This should give you the same effect and simplify your code.

Comment: Well, i wonder how to change background-position in correct way for this hover ...

Comment: using jQuery you can animate any CSS property, including `background-position`

Comment: Ok, i will do it when i have chance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed http://jsfiddle.net/kvkUB/3/